# Python can't import the module I made

Tags: python-3.x, setuptools, importerror, toml

I created a python class file that I wanted to modulize for windows machines, so I have been following this [tutorial](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/tutorials/packaging-projects/).

Structure:

```
projfolder/
    mymodule/
        mymodule.py
        __init__.py
        __main__.py
    tests/
    LICENSE
    MANIFEST.in
    README.md
    pyproject.toml
```

`pyproject.toml`

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=61.0"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "mymodule"
version = "1.0"
authors = [
    {name="author", email="author@gmail.com"}
]
description = "description"
readme = "README.md"
license = {file="LICENSE"}
requires-python = ">=3.6"
classifiers = [
     'Development Status :: status',
     'Intended Audience :: for Author',
     'Operating System :: OS Independent',
     'Programming Language :: Python3',
     'Topic :: topic :: topic',
]
```

as per the tutorial, after I have configured my MANIFEST, README, and LICENSE, I open a command prompt and run

```
py -m pip install --upgrade build
py -m build
pip install ./dist/mymodule-1.0.tar.gz
```

which outputs no errors or warnings.

When I run `pip show mymodule`, it can find it, shows me the path, etc. When I travel to the path in a file explorer, it shows me these files in the mymodule folder: `__init__.py, __main__.py, mymodule.py`. However, when I run

```
python
import mymodule
mymodule.myclass
```

it can't find "myclass" associated with it. What are the potential reasons why this is happening and how can it be fixed?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Doi! You need to use `__init__.py` to import the module into the namespace! (Everything I've ever read has left it empty... I just opened up another module and explored it to figure that out)

`__init__.py`:

```
from . import mymodule
```